# How to show suggestions when p-autoComplete gets focused

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete, primeng

I am using [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) from [primefaces.org](https://www.primefaces.org/)

Everything is working well. But I have a small problem. When using `p-autoComplete`, when `p-autoComplete` is focused it does not show suggestions. I mean I have to type something to get suggestions. I think it is the default behavior. But I want to change it.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to set `[minLength]="0"`, but no luck!!!!!!!!

Comment: That's how it behaves

Comment: @Aravind Can't I change it's behavior?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

This works for me .

(onFocus)="autoComplete.handleDropdownClick()"

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has a few answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some default items in to the suggestions property as

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="val" [suggestions]="results" field="name"></p-autoComplete>
```

and you should be using in component code

```
results = ['a', 'b']
```

When you are loading from service you need to either clear or append to same array

Comment: I am exactly doing the same thing but still not able to show suggestions as soon as `p-autoComplete` is **focused**.

Comment: I am getting the results if I type in some character or even if I clear the p-autoComplete's value by using backspace or delete key, then also I get suggestions.

Comment: actually why you want to have some populated values in that case you should go for a dropdown

Comment: I personally think that its a good user experience when suggestions opens as soon as he focuses it. I might use dropdown as you said but there is a problem with it. Here is the demo page of dropdown: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown I want to use editable dropdown. But problem with that is that it does not open suggestions if it was keyboard focused. I have to click it with mouse to open the suggestions. Please try it yourself.

Comment: if you want we can create one new auto complete instead of exisiting ones

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the autocomplete.js file and add some code to onInputFocus like this

```
    AutoComplete.prototype.onInputFocus = function (event) {
    this.focus = true;
    var queryValue = this.multiple ? this.multiInputEL.nativeElement.value : this.inputEL.nativeElement.value;
    if (this.dropdownMode === 'blank')
      this.search(event, '');
    else if (this.dropdownMode === 'current')
      this.search(event, queryValue);
    this.onDropdownClick.emit({
      originalEvent: event,
      query: queryValue
    });
    this.onFocus.emit(event);
};
```

you can right-click on p-autoComplete to get you there, beware of updates, when you update prime-ng you will have to do it again.